# Spring boot use resources templates folder with JSP templates instead of webapp folder?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, templates, spring-boot

I started a Spring Boot MVC project and realized that there are two folder within `resources`. One is called `templates` and the other `static`. I really like this folder setup.

The problem is that I use JSP Templates for my views. I could not place a `.jsp` template inside the `templates` folder and got it to work.
What I needed to do is to create a `webapp` folder on the same level as `src` and `resources`. Placing my JSP templates in there and then my views can be found.

What do I need to reconfigure to actually use my JSP templates within the `templates` folder which lies within `resources`?

Comment: If you want to use Thymeleaf for the template then you can check example at https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-thymeleaf/

Comment: As I said - JSP only. The `templates` stuff does work for TL I know that

Comment: Actually you mentioned JSP template so I assumed you mean TL, I dont think you can have jsp inside the resources folder. JSPs should be inside the webapp.

Comment: If you are starting a new project don't use JSP. Use something like Thymeleaf. JSP will only work in the web app locations and other resource locations specified by the servlet spec.

Comment: I have no option to use something else because JSP is company standard

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Moreover thymeleaf is not compatible with several client sided templating engines, even simple mustache. Since it tries to parse everything, it simply reports errors for those. In other words, it sucks. JSP is old as hell, but it can do everything TL does and more.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You can't drop a JSP into a browser to view the page, whereas TL allows you to do just that.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

According to the [Maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) `src/main/resources` will end up in `WEB-INF/classes` in the WAR.

This does the trick for Spring Boot in your `application.properties`:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/classes/templates
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp
```

If you prefer Java configuration this is the way to go:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/classes/templates/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return bean;
    }
}
```

**Update with a full example**

This example was based on [Spring's initializer](https://start.spring.io/) (Gradle project with "Web" dependency). I just added `apply plugin: 'war'` to the `build.gradle`, added/changed the files below, built teh project with `gradle war` and deployed it to my application server (Tomcat 8).

This is the directory tree of this sample project:

```
\---src
    +---main
        +---java
        |   \---com
        |       \---example
        |           \---demo
        |                   ApplicationConfiguration.java
        |                   DemoApplication.java
        |                   DemoController.java
        |
        \---resources
            +---static
            \---templates
                    index.jsp
```

ApplicationConfiguration.java: see above

DemoApplication.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

DemoController.java:

```
@Controller
public class DemoController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

index.jsp:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: All I get is a 500 / unexpected error: "Circular view path [/WEB-INF/classes/templates/some.jsp]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/WEB-INF/classes/templates/some.jsp] again.". I used a fresh blank project with a single JSP file and both your suggestions.

Comment: Here you go, one free bounty for an answer that doesn't work. However, it's closer to it than the accepted answer IMHO.

Comment: @dagnelies Thanks for the bounty. I edited my post with my running sample project. Are you building a WAR and deploying it to an app server? Executable JAR and WAR don't play well with Spring Boot and JSP due to [limitations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations). It might work for JSP if you put them in `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp` according to this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-with-jsps-in-executable-jars-1) but that is not what the OP wanted

Comment: worked for me thank you. In my case added my jsp in WEB-INF/jsp and all the HTML, CSS, JS in main/resources/public. referred to them by /WEB-INF/classes/public

Comment: I used `spring.mvc.view.prefix = /WEB-INF/classes/templates/` and it doens't work. I don't understand why because when I look into the war file, the directory exists but I still receive a 404

Answer (score 9):

## Official information:

### Resource handling:

> Links to resources are rewritten at runtime in template, thanks to a
>   ResourceUrlEncodingFilter, auto-configured for Thymeleaf and
>   FreeMarker. You should manually declare this filter when using JSPs.
>   [source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)

### Supported template engine

> As well as REST web services, you can also use Spring MVC to serve
>   dynamic HTML content. Spring MVC supports a variety of templating
>   technologies including Thymeleaf, FreeMarker and JSPs.

[...]

> JSPs should be avoided if possible, there are several known limitations
>   when using them with embedded servlet containers.

[..]

> When you’re using one of these templating engines with the default
>   configuration, your templates will be picked up automatically from
>   src/main/resources/templates.

[source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-template-engines)

### Spring boot JSP limitations

> - With Tomcat it should work if you use war packaging, i.e. an    executable war will work, and will also be deployable to a standard
>     container (not limited to, but including Tomcat).
> - An executable jar    will not work because of a hard coded file pattern in Tomcat.
> - With    Jetty it should work if you use war packaging, i.e. an executable war    will work, and will also be deployable to any
>     standard container.
> - Undertow does not support JSPs.
> - Creating a custom error.jsp page    won’t override the default view for error handling, custom error    pages should be used instead.

[source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations)

### Technical change

Tell spring boot to from where to load the `JSP files`. In `application.properties` set

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

[source](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-template-engines)

### Sample spring boot with JSP

In case you do want to use `JSP` with spring boot here are two examples:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.5.9.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp

https://github.com/joakime/spring-boot-jsp-demo

Comment: I think this answer beats around the bush. The issue is not to use/display JSPs. The OP clearly stated he can already do that. It is to configure Spring to use the standard `templates` folder to lookup the JSPs instead of "bypassing" the lookup mechanism by using the `webapp/WEB-INF`. From your answer, it is still not clear to me how to do so. The first example fetches them from the `webapp` directory, the second uses the special `META-INF`/`WEB-INF` combo. It's similar to what the OP already did. How get them directly from `templates` is still unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize it, *none* of the suggested answers worked for me so far. Using a blank Spring boot starter project.

**Somehow, something looks hardwired inside Spring or servlets so that JSP *must* be in `/webapp` (or a subfolder).** Unlike default thymeleaf templates which are looked up in `/resources/templates`.

I tried all kind of changes, really a lot of different configurations, but wasn't able to modify that behavior. It just produced complexity and was unable to serve the JSPs anymore. So, bottom line, if you're using JSPs, just put them in `/webapp`. It also works by addding *zero* configuration using a controller like:

`@GetMapping("/foo")
public String serveFoo() {
    return "relative-path-inside-webapp/foo.jsp";
}`

On another note, by default, the `/webapp` folder will also be hidden in the Spring Toolsuite, so you'll have to manually configure it as a "source folder".

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have `welcome.jsp` file in `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\jsp\welcome.jsp` and you have these config: `spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/` and `spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp`

it works with `mvn spring-boot:run`
if you want that you run your jar file with `java -jar java -jar spring-boot-web-jsp.jar` command just copy `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF` to `src\main\resources\META-INF\resources`

file `welcome.jsp` should be in `src\main\resources\META-INF\resources\WEB-INF\jsp\welcome.jsp`

also according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43169588/5050750) he `found that since 1.4.3 version and above stops supporting the embedded JSPs`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get JSP Resolved from templates folder with this in my Application Config...

```
    @Bean
@Description("Thymeleaf template resolver serving HTML 5")
public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver() {

    var templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();

    templateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("JAVASCRIPT");
    templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
@Description("Thymeleaf template engine with Spring integration")
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {

    var templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());

    return templateEngine;
}

@Bean
@Description("Thymeleaf view resolver")
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

    var viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();

    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    return viewResolver;
}

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
}
```