# Springboot doesn't return view

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, thymeleaf

I am using spring boot for rendering a page. I am using theamleaf too. But I am getting below provided exception while calling it from browser.

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "index", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:246) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:59) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

I have written view resolver class when i have used `InternalResourceViewResolver` for this.
`MvcConfiguration.class`

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan
        public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
            InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new 
    InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolver.setViewNames("jsp");
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }
    }
```

Same I have mentioned in `application.yml` too.
**application.yml** is

```
spring:
  mvc:
    view:
      prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
      suffix: .jsp
      view-names: jsp
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: localhost:9092
      bindings:
        greetings-in:
          destination: greetings
          contentType: application/json
        greetings-out:
          destination: greetings
          contentType: application/json
```

This is my Controller class which is responsible for rendering index.jsp
MainController.class

```
    import java.util.Map;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

    @Controller
    public class MainController {

        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String home(Map<String, Object> model) {
            model.put("message", "HowToDoInJava Reader !!");
            return "index";
        }
    }
```

[image: project structure]

Comment: What is a directory structure of your project? Where is index.jsp located?

Comment: it's /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp

Comment: Do you have thymeleaf starter added to your pom? I don't think it's necesarry to create MvcConfiguration.

Comment: yes i added that too .  Previously, I had tried to access the same page without MvcConfiguration class. But it was giving same exception

Comment: Try on removing MvcConfiguration class, and place your index.jsp in resources/templates directory.

Comment: ok . Also, Do i need to change anything on  application.yml ?

Comment: It's also kinda weird that you mix jsp with thymeleaf that uses more plain html style...

Comment: How is it going? Did it work?

Comment: Nope. I tried by removing thtmeleaf too and it's showing 404 not found . Don't know why am I not able to do this simple thing ?

Comment: @SritamJagadev Can you post your `pom.xml`

Answer (score 0):

> First option: We have a project [Spring Boot] where we have not
>   created any configs for using thymeleaf. You just need to create files
>   in the directory of resources -> templates [index.html] and just
>   simply use it in your controller
>
> Option two: Set spring.thymeleaf.template-resolver-order=0 in the application.properties file.As part of the next step create custom ClassLoaderTemplateResolver

@Configuration
    public class CustomConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

```
@Bean
public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver yourTemplateResolver() {
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver configurer = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    configurer.setPrefix("customLocation/");
    configurer.setSuffix(".html");
    configurer.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    configurer.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    configurer.setOrder(0);  // this is important. This way spring //boot will listen to both places 0 and 1
    configurer.setCheckExistence(true    return configurer;
}}
```

[More info can be found here](https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-thymeleaf/)

**If you need also security config add below code into gradle**

```
//----------------------------------Thymeleaf----------------------------------//
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf.extras/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4
compile group: 'org.thymeleaf.extras', name: 'thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5', version: '3.0.4.RELEASE'
```

**Create one file for**

```
 @Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(SpringSecurityDialect::class)
class ThymeleafSecurityDialectConfiguration protected constructor() {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    fun securityDialect(): SpringSecurityDialect {
        return SpringSecurityDialect()
    }
}
```

> If you want to set JSP directory to resources -> templates folder just refer to this answer. this issue has already been solved

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48285180/8814467)

Comment: I am trying to access a jsp not html. So is it going to work ?

Comment: Or u just need to put jsp files in that directory?