# Bootstrap can't be located?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Currently working on a web application (Spring). Trying to setup bootstrap test table for the application and apply various themes to the table. However, it appears Bootstrap cannot be located. I don't know if this is a simple "I entered the wrong path" issue, or if this is a larger setup problem.

My file layout is currently as follows:

[image: File Structure]

I tried the fully qualified name, just from the assets portion, swapping '/'s in and out, no luck. I reviewed the bootstrap documentation, but there isn't much if you are not using the CDN links, which I cannot.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="/Grief/src/main/resources/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="/Grief/src/main/resources/assets/font/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="/Grief/src/main/resources/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" /></script>
```

and

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="/assets/font/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
...
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" /></script>
```

Among others, yet the table continues to look un-bootstrapped (below).

[image]

**=====The full project layout=====**

[image]

**Chrome's console window:**

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: where is the HTML file located?

Comment: Let me add that in

Comment: which file contains the HTML code with the bootstrap link, helloworld.html or list-employees.html?

Comment: Check with your Browsers inspector where it tries to locate the BS files

Comment: @theBashShell the HTML file I want to be accessed is list-employees.html

Comment: The issue has something to do with Spring(don't have Spring experience). But, you can refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46183633/spring-boot-use-resources-templates-folder-with-jsp-templates-instead-of-webapp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**These files need to be located in the `static` folder**. They can be referenced in the following way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link href="/font/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The `static` file is inferred by Spring as the starting location (unless changed in the config). Include the file paths only *after* the `static` folder.

[image: a]

Answer (score 1):

Try this path because other files are also there:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```