# Spring boot does not load jsp file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, thymeleaf

Using spring boot starter `2.4.1 version`.

resources folder has the following structure. As it is seen hello.jsp is in templates folder. These are included in application.properties:

```
  spring.mvc.view.prefix=/templates/
  spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

And a simple **controller:**

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String index(){
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

But get **404**.

*Controller method is entering for sure.*

Tried what is suggested in the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48285180/7225171), tried using the webapp, but didn't help: **/WEB-INF** is not created inside target **at all**, it seems maven is ignoring webapp and WEB-INF folders.

[image: target]

Comment: How do you know the 'controller method is entering for sure'?

Comment: Debugging, logging.

Comment: The files are loaded from `classpath:/templates` NOT `templates`. That and JSP only works with a WAR file not a JAR file and is limited.

Comment: @M.Deinum you are right. That's what is set by spring-boot for thymeleaf: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.M1/reference/html/common-application-properties.html. But when I set `classpath:/templates` in my properties file (without adding thymleafe dependency) it doesn't work. So the only (and I am sure not the effective) solution I found was adding thymleaf dependency into pom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just restarting Inellij IDEA with invalidating caches (`File | Invalidate Caches / Restart`) solved the problem.

Actually it started to work with templates folder, so templates are the root, and if you put something inside it, you can access from controllers without any `prefix` setting.

But again nothing is workable from **webapp**, seams maven is ignoring **webapp** at all. Maybe this is connected with maven, or spring-boot version.

And add **[thymeleafe](https://www.thymeleaf.org/)** dependency and it will work with `.html` files (this is not the thing I like, but up to now the only workable solution found).

Answer (score 0):

try to change your configs and codes like below:

```
in application.properties put these configs:

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp


LoginForm class:
    public class LoginForm {
        private String email;
        private String password;

        public LoginForm() {}
        public String getEmail() { return email; }
        public void setEmail(String email) { this.email = email; }
        public String getPassword() { return password; }
        public void setPassword(String password) { this.password = password; }
    }

**LoginForm is just a normal bean with a no-arg Constructor and the getters / setters**

Now, we create a LoginHandler Class to coordinate and handle the whole login process.

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public class LoginHandler {
    private static final String LOGIN_VIEW = "login";
    private static final String LOGOUT_VIEW = "logout";
    }

let’s define some handler methods.

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String showLoginView(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("loginForm", new LoginForm());
    return LOGIN_VIEW;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

okay, i will fix your code and run in your IDE,

```js
 @RequestMapping("/hello")
public String index() {
    return "hello";
}
```

Comment: This is not the case. Method *index()* is getting called in my code correctly. Problem is with jsp file location / path or something else.

Comment: Yes, I have tired it.