# Whitelabel error Spring Boot - Project structure

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I know questions on this specific topic have been asked many times so far, but I can't find an exact solution for my problem and it gets really annoying. I'm writing a Spring Boot app, everything seems to be fine, but it doesn't give the `jsp` pages that I described. I think it's related to my class structure, I did researched it but unable to solve. Please, take a look. Thanks.

This is the result I get

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40Euz.png)

I want to get the specific `jsp` page which is what I normally should

This is my class structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWMNk.png)

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>CRM</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>CRM</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-devtools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/htmlunit-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <!-- 
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <!-- <scope>compileOnly</scope> -->
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/oracle/ojdbc6 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-hikaricp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-hikaricp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Main App class

```
package com.example.CRM;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan("com.example.CRM.entity")
@EntityScan(basePackages="com.example.CRM")
@SpringBootApplication
public class CrmApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(CrmApplication.class);
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CrmApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Configuration:

```
package com.example.CRM;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CrmApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

}
```

Controller:

```
package com.example.CRM.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.example.CRM.dao.CRMStaff;
import com.example.CRM.entity.CRM;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class CRMController {

    @GetMapping
    public String getHome()
    {
        return "home";
    }

    @Autowired
    private CRMStaff crmStaff;

    @GetMapping("/staff")
    public String getCrmStaff(Model theModel)
    {
        List<CRM> list = crmStaff.getStaffMembers();
        theModel.addAttribute("staff", list);

        return "list";
    }

}
```

DAO:

```
package com.example.CRM.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.example.CRM.entity.CRM;

public interface CRMStaff {

    public List<CRM> getStaffMembers();

}
```

DAO Implementation

```
package com.example.CRM.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.example.CRM.entity.CRM;

@Component
@Repository
public class CRMStaffImpl implements CRMStaff {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<CRM> getStaffMembers() {

        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query<CRM> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("from CRM", CRM.class);
        List<CRM> list = theQuery.getResultList();

        return list;
    }

}
```

Entity:

```
package com.example.CRM.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="CRMMembers")
public class CRM {

    @Id
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Member_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name="phoneNum")
    private String phoneNum;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="address")
    private String address;

}
```

home.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>CRM project | Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Customer Relation Management</h1>
        <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/staff">Get List of Members</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

list.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>CRM | Staff Members</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>CRM Staff Members List</h3>
        <hr>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Address</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach var="temp" items="${staff }">
                <tr>
                    <td>${temp.firstName }</td>
                    <td>${temp.lastName }</td>
                    <td>${temp.phoneNum }</td>
                    <td>${temp.email }</td>
                    <td>${temp.address }</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please describe or show what result you are getting and describe how you expect it to be different.

Comment: @ordonezalex edited

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29784088. Do you have those dependencies in your project? Please include your build file (Gradle, Maven, etc) in the question.

Comment: @ordonezalex added pom.xml

Comment: The whitelabel error page does not tell you what went wrong apart from the 404. 404 usually occur if there is no resource for the URI / request, or that there is a wrong mapping (view mapping in this case). The latter is very likely since @ordonezalex version with a view mapping to jsp seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Your project works for me when I add these properties to  `application.properties`.

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Here is a repository for you to try: https://github.com/a-p-o/stackoverflow-whitelabel-error-spring-boot-project-structure

Comment: Well, yours is working fine. Mine is maybe a bit more complicated, database connection and so on. What else do you think can cause this problem? Maybe another problem occurs and at the end it gives such whitelabel page

Comment: I'm gonna write all thing from scratch. By doing it step by step again, then maybe I'll figure out what the problem really was.