# Spring boot: 404 error when calling JSP using controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, dependency-injection, http-status-code-404

I'm getting the following error when running my project using Spring Tool Suite,

[image]

But in case my problem is I have already added the appropriate dependencies to `pom.XML` file. So what could be the problem?

My `pom.XML` file dependencies as follows,

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

My controller `ApplicationController.java` as follows,

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class ApplicationController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String Welcome() {
        return "welcomepage";
    }
}
```

My vives are in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/view/welcomepage.jsp` you can look the tree view below,

[image]

And I have already changed the `application.properties` file as well. But still, I can't understand what is wrong.

My `application.properties` file as follows,

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

I just print hello in My `welcomepage.jsp`,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
hello
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which complete URL are you calling?

Comment: Put your jsp file under **src/main/java/resources/static**

Comment: @Dhanraj Then it will be the same noh? I have to change my application.properties as well

Comment: @LppEdd what are you meening from complete url

Comment: @Mr.Semicolon like "http://localhost:8080/domain/" etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you was very close to the working application. The main issue in your code is in `<scope>provided</scope>` for your Jasper dependency.
And also looks like you are running your code from eclipse IDE through the `main` method.

Long story short:

If you would like to run your application through the `main` method in `MyApplication.java` then just remove scope `provided` for the Jasper.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Or you can run your application exactly in that state like you have right now from the console:

```
mvn clean spring-boot:run
```

But I suggest to remove this scope so you could be able to run your code from IDE and from console. In addition to that looks like `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency is redundant (it must be available within `spring-boot-starter-web`). In a nutshell please try to use following pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Hope my answer will help you.

Comment: In both variants? Through the console and IDE?

Comment: @Mr.Semicolon so let me know if it still doesn't work in your case.

Answer (score 6):

You may also need to add this in pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

---

UPDATE 1:

**JSP Limitation**

When running a Spring Boot application that uses an embedded servlet container (and is packaged as an executable archive), there are some limitations in the JSP support.

- With Jetty and Tomcat, it should work if you use war packaging. An
  executable war will work when launched with java -jar, and will also be deployable to any standard container. JSPs are not supported when using an executable jar.
- Undertow does not support JSPs.
- Creating a custom error.jsp page does not override the default view
  for error handling. Custom error pages should be used instead.

---

**Scope**

`compile` This is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project. Furthermore, those dependencies are propagated to dependent projects.

`provided` This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

`runtime` This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath.

Also, Try to change the Following in tomcat-embed-jasper

```
Remove <scope>provided</scope> OR change the scope to compile <scope>compile</scope>
```

[JSP Limitations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-jsp-limitations)
[Spring Boot JSP 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782915/spring-boot-jsp-404)

Comment: @Mr.Semicolon which packaging option are you using jar or war?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to generate a jar from my application and then run it with java -jar myapp.jar But I only managed to run this jar with the version below spring-boot-starter-parent:

MyApp/pom.xml:

```
      <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
  </parent>
```

I researched in:
[Spring Boot JSP 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782915/spring-boot-jsp-404)