# getting 404 error message while parsing request from 1 jsp file to other

Tags: java, spring

I am using spring MVC, while parsing request from 1 JSP file to other JSP file getting 404 error message

> "The requested resource is not available".

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

@RequestMapping("/login.jsp")
public ModelAndView helloWord() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("login");
    model.addObject("msg", "AYM Registration Form");

    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value="/success.jsp",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView successMessage(@RequestParam Map<String,String> reqPar) {

    String name = reqPar.get("name");
    String age = reqPar.get("age");
    String gender = reqPar.get("gender");

    ModelAndView model1 = new ModelAndView("success");
    model1.addObject("msg", "You have successfully submitted your data..Pls find: Name="+name+"Age="+age+"gender="+gender);

    return model1;
}
}
```

login.jsp:

```
<form action="success.jsp" method="POST">
```

spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ClassesManagement.Controllers" />

<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Error Message:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /FirstMVCProject/success.jsp
type Status report
message /FirstMVCProject/success.jsp
description The requested resource is not available.
```

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55312660/spring-boot-404-error-when-calling-jsp-using-controller/55315801#55315801