# Why are none of the API's in controller working?

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, model-view-controller

I am a beginner to Spring Boot. Here is my controller

```
@Controller
public class StudentController {
    @Autowired
    StudentService studentService;

@GetMapping("/")
public ModelAndView getAllStudents() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index");
    List<Student> studentList = studentService.getAll();
    mav.addObject("students", studentList);
    return mav;
}

@GetMapping("/add-student")
public ModelAndView addStudent() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("add_student");
    mav.addObject("command", new Student());
    return mav;
}

@PostMapping("/save-student")
public String saveStaff(@ModelAttribute Student student) {
    studentService.save(student);
    return "redirect:/";
}


@GetMapping("/student-update/{id}")
public ModelAndView updateStudent(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("add_student");
    Student student = studentService.getById(id);
    mav.addObject("command", student);
    return mav;
}

@GetMapping("/student-delete/{id}")
public String deleteStaff(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
    Student deleteStaff = studentService.getById(id);
    studentService.delete(deleteStaff);
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Here is project structure, my JSP files are in same location as specified in application.properties:
[image]

Here is my application.properties:

```
server.port=8080
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username= postgres
spring.datasource.password= pgadmin
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation= true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.mvc.view.prefix:/WEB-INF/jsp/

spring.view.suffix:.jsp
spring.view.view-names:jsp/*
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

For API `http://localhost:8080/add-student` response is

```
{
    "timestamp": "2024-01-02T13:33:48.722+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/add-student/"
}
```

pom.xml of the code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springjava.poc</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring_Boot_CRUD_With_JSP</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Spring_Boot_CRUD_With_JSP</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>16</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Even if I set a **server.servlet.context-path** explicitly, then modify API accordingly and run still error comes. The code runs without errors in the IDE, but none of the API's give results.

Comment: Are you targeting the path `/add-student` or `/add-student/`? Try `@GetMapping({"/add-student", "/add-student/"})` and tell if this works.

Comment: @Slevin I am targeting /add-student  I tried the GetMapping you gave but the API response is same

Comment: The response says something else. Anyhow, added the additional path and tried it out?

Comment: @Slevin Yes I tried the additional path, the response is same except the last trailing slash {
    "timestamp": "2024-01-02T14:29:45.077+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/add-student/"
}

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the following:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Instead of:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix:/WEB-INF/jsp/

spring.view.suffix:.jsp
spring.view.view-names:jsp/*
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

If you are using JSPs in your Spring Boot application, seems like you need the tomcat-embed-jasper dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

For a jar packaged application, remove the provided part, you can check it in your `pom.xml` by looking `<packaging></packaging>` tag.

Comment: Okay done, but API responses are still same.

Comment: Can you please share your `pom.xml` file? Make sure that you have `tomcat-embed-jasper` dependency. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Okay shared pom.xml in question. I don't have provided part inside <packaging> and I already have tomcat-embed-jasper

Comment: remove unnecessary duplications from your `pom.xml` file:
`tomcat-embed-jasper` and `lombok`  mentioned twice in your config. 
Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782915/spring-boot-jsp-404

Comment: Okay removed them and attached revised pom.xml in question. Restarted intellij but api results are still same {
    "timestamp": "2024-01-02T15:58:58.035+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/add-student/"
}

Comment: As I said, please carefully read this and try all the options: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782915/spring-boot-jsp-404
especially part related to  "Working directory" -> $MODULE_DIR$: