# Spring Boot 404 when running in AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, java-17

I am building my first Spring Boot web application and have deployed it to AWS using elastic beanstalk. I have confirmed that the application loads and runs correctly in my local machine and am running it using simple Vs Code launch config.

```
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "SpringBootApplication",
            "request": "launch",
            "mainClass": "com.package.webapp.MyWebApplication",
            "projectName": "webapp",
            "args": "--server.port=8080"
        }
```

The log shows this out put when I run locally.

```
2024-01-04T10:08:28.136-07:00 DEBUG 26044 --- \[nio-8080-exec-1\] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to \[/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp\]
2024-01-04T10:08:28.566-07:00 DEBUG 26044 --- \[nio-8080-exec-1\] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
```

I also have confirmation that the spring boot application is being hit from my build deployed because I am able to get a response from this mapping. So that tells me most of the spring application is functioning correctly.

```
    @RequestMapping("test")
    @ResponseBody
    public String returnTestStringToBody() {
        return "Testing!!";
    }
```

The problem I am experiencing is when I try to reach the jsp mapped pages I get this error.

[image]

> Whitelabel Error Page 
>  
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
> Thu Jan 04 14:24:54 UTC 2024 
> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

This is where my jsp is located

```
my-webapp\src\main\resources\META-INF\resources\WEB-INF\jsp\home.jsp
```

This is what is in my application properties

```
# View Configuration

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

This is included in my pom

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

This is my request mapping.

```
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String root() {
        return "home";
    }
```

The controller is located here.

```
my-webapp\src\main\java\com\package\webapp\controllers\home\HomeController.java
```

I see the following log entries.

```
Jan  4 14:56:14 ip-172-31-9-120 web[11872]: 2024-01-04T14:56:14.992Z DEBUG 11872 --- [nio-5000-exec-5] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp]
Jan  4 14:56:14 ip-172-31-9-120 web[11872]: 2024-01-04T14:56:14.993Z DEBUG 11872 --- [nio-5000-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
```

Note: This is the whole home controller and the latter `/test` mapping returns the “Testing !!” text appropriately.

```
package com.package.webapp.controllers.home;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;


@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String root() {
        return "home";
    }
   
    @RequestMapping("test")
    @ResponseBody
    public String returnTestStringToBody() {
        return "Testing!!";
    }
}
```

Note: I have reviewed and confirmed what is in this post. [Spring Boot JSP 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782915/spring-boot-jsp-404)

**Update 01/05/2024:**
I have tried some more things. Based on a suggestion. I have now tried to move the jsp to the following path and redeployed with no change.

```
my-webapp\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\jsp\home.jsp
```

I also accidentally double clicked on the jar in my local windows machine and discovered that the process was running and the service was listening on port 8080. Now when I go to the page the issue is replicated locally now. So there is some difference between running it via vs code and trying to run the bundled jar. Hope this extra info helps?